# SAS Hash object sum

Tags: sas

**I am trying to understand the sum() function of SAS Hash object**. To my understanding, suminc: defines the variable **the SAS hash object keeps track of while sum()** will sum up the values of that variable.

Suppose I have the data set

```
data sample;
    input id x;
    datalines;
1 350
1 220
1 300
2 300
2 500
;
run;
```

**I want the aggregation to be**

```
id x_sum
2  800
1  870
```

However, my hash code:

```
data _null_;
    set sample end= done;

    length x_sum 8;

    if _N_ = 1 then 
    do;
        declare hash T(suminc:"x");
        T.definekey("id");
        T.definedata("id");
        T.definedata("x_sum");
        T.definedone();
    end;


    T.ref();

    T.sum(sum:x_sum);

    put _all_;


    T.replace();

    if done then T.output(dataset: "my_set");

run;
```

outputs:

```
id x_sum
2  800
1  520
```

as a data set and to the log:

```
done=0 id=1 x=350 x_sum=350 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
done=0 id=1 x=220 x_sum=570 _ERROR_=0 _N_=2
**done=0 id=1 x=300 x_sum=520 _ERROR_=0 _N_=3**
done=0 id=2 x=300 x_sum=300 _ERROR_=0 _N_=4
done=1 id=2 x=500 x_sum=800 _ERROR_=0 _N_=5
```

Can anyone explain to me what is happening?

**UPDATE AFTER ALL THE COMMENTS**:

Hi all, I am totally new to Stack Overflow so I am still figuring out this "Tick off answer" system... I felt every one contributed something.

Anyway, after a lot of experiments, I figured out what was happening -

Basically, **whenever <strike>.sum()</strike> .replace() is called, the sum counter is reset to zero.** This, <strike>and not really replace() etc</strike>, is the reason why the results was what it was - the sum() reset my count and so ref() was only ever summing the previous 2 observations.

Hope this is useful information to everyone. If others have any insight, please do share.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "whenever .sum() is called, the sum counter is reset to zero". That would suggest that .sum() isn't very useful. Did you try it after commenting out the replace()?  When i do, the put statements now return what you want. I'm still stuck on replace() as the problem. I think each time replace() is called it resets the counter before increment it. Will play with it tonight and post more.

Comment: Added an answer with quote from docs explaining that REPLACE() reinitializes the summary value.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. It is "replace()" which resets the counter, not sum()!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of Replace().  From the docs (9.3 language reference concpets, using the hash object):

> This SUMINC tag instructs the hash object to allocate internal storage for maintaining a summary value for each key. 
>   The summary value of a hash key is initialized to the value of the
>   SUMINC variable whenever the ADD or REPLACE method is used.  The
>   summary value of a hash key is incremented by the value of the SUMINC
>   variable whenever the FIND, CHECK, or REF method is used.

I think an important point is that the "summary value" is not the DATA step variable x_sum, or x_sum stored as data variable in the hash table.  It's stored outside of the hash table's defined data.  It's ancillary information that is really an attribute of the key.  (in my head...)

If you comment out the replace(), your code works (you get the right value for x_sum in the PDV), but the problem is that x_sum is never written to the hash table.  So you called replace() to write x_sum to the hash table, causing the unfortunate side effect that the summary value is initialized to the value of x.  I think a workaround answer is to assign x=x_sum before you call replace().  That way when replace() reinitializes the summary value to the value of x, x holds the current summary value.  Hard for me to put in words, but see below added just one statement.

```
data _null_;
  set sample end= done;

  length x_sum 8;

  if _N_ = 1 then 
  do;
    declare hash T(suminc:"x");
    T.definekey("id");
    T.definedata("id");
    T.definedata("x_sum");
    T.definedone();
  end;
  T.ref();
  T.sum(sum:x_sum);
  put _all_;

  x=x_sum;  *Replace method will initialize the summary value to x! ;

  T.replace();
  if done then T.output(dataset: "my_set");
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the T.REPLACE() is part of your problem.  I don't know what good that would do, only bad.  If you comment it out, the PUT _ ALL _ shows what you want.  The surprise to me (still new to SAS hashing), is that I couldn't get T.Output() to write the x_sum variable to the output dataset.  Hopefully someone else will chime in.  Perhaps these suminc accumulators are handled differently?  In below, since the PDV had the correct data, I switched to write the output data set in the normal DATA step fashion, rather than using output()

```
data my_set(keep=id x_sum);
  set sample;
  by id;

  if _N_ = 1 then 
  do;
    declare hash T(suminc:"x");
    T.definekey("id");
    T.definedata("x");
    T.definedone();
  end;

  T.ref();

  T.sum(sum:x_sum);

  put _all_;

  if last.id;
run;
```

Comment: I can't check as I don't have sas on my phone(!) but couple the reason for `T.Output()` not working for you be because you don't have a  `T.definedata("x_sum");` in the hash table?

Comment: @Bendy, I had tried that, and couldn't get it working.  The docs say "This SUMINC tag instructs the hash object to allocate internal storage for maintaining a summary value for each key."  I'm thinking its not possible to store that value in the hash table.  Maybe that is what Matt was trying to do with replace().  Happy to be shown I'm wrong; I'm still a hash newbie.

Comment: The way I understood the function was that "T.replace()" would update T with the newest x_sum. This is what I was trying to do.

Comment: Replace() is definitely the problem.  Posting another answer, since couldn't edit this one in a way that wouldn't make the comments confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe you can try these codes:
data _null_;

length x_sum 8;

if _N_ = 1 then 
do;
    declare hash T(suminc:"x");
    T.definekey("id");
    T.definedata("id");
    T.definedata("x_ct","x_sum");
    T.definedone();
end;

do until(done);
  set sample end = done;
  if t.find() ^= 0 then do;
     x_ct = 0;
     x_sum = 0;
  end;
  x_ct ++ 1;
  x_sum ++ x;
  t.replace();
 end;
 t.output(dataset:'want');
 stop;
run;
```

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine and that is what I ended up doing in the end.

What I was trying to figure is why my original code wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you're declaring your hash table, your key `ID` is not unique for each record. You can fix it by including the multidata method: `multidata:"yes"`:

```
if _N_ = 1 then 
do;
    declare hash T(suminc:"x", multidata:"yes");
    T.definekey("id");
    T.definedata("id");
    T.definedata("x_sum");
    T.definedone();
end;
```

This gives:

```
done=0 id=1 x=350 x_sum=350 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
done=0 id=1 x=220 x_sum=570 _ERROR_=0 _N_=2
**done=0 id=1 x=300 x_sum=870 _ERROR_=0 _N_=3**
done=0 id=2 x=300 x_sum=300 _ERROR_=0 _N_=4
done=1 id=2 x=500 x_sum=800 _ERROR_=0 _N_=5
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think he wants multidata.  His desired output is one record per ID., and I think he wants a hash table with only two items in it.

Comment: @Quentin Ah yes you're right thanks...and the replace() is also why he gets the value x_sum=520 - because after summing to 570, the replace method is setting the x_sum value back to the value in the PDV (220) before adding on the next value for the key id value

Comment: That's right, I wasn't looking for multidata. The replace IS re-setting the sum. However, I don't know why.